# Dynamic struct with result object in Go Language

Tags: json, go, beego

I want to create result object json with dynamic structure of data, ex
in func1 the result is like this

```
{
  'result': 'this is result',
  'content': {
    'func1'  : 'value',
    'some_desc_func1': 'value'
  }
}
```

and func2 maybe the result is *just* (focus on content) like this

```
{
  'result': 'this is result',
  'content': {
    'func2'  : 'value'
  }
}
```

As this reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657622/4476788, i want to show result json with just one key of result.

Like this

```html
{
  'result': 'this is result',
  'content': {
    'key'  : 'value'
  }
}
```

And not like this

```html
[
  {
    'result_1' : 'answer 1'
  },
  {
    'result_2' : 'answer 2'
  }
]
```

i try to update the play ground of the answer but it showing error

```
type Brand struct {
   Name string
}

var database map[string]interface{}

func init() {
  database = make(map[string]interface{})

  brands := make([]Brand, 1)
  brands = Brand{"Gucci"}

  database["brands"] = brands
}
```

You can try run in here https://play.golang.org/p/mKCwKEVI7E

it showing error

*tmp/sandbox651609402/main.go:22: cannot use Brand literal (type Brand) as type []Brand in assignment*

Comment: `brands[0] = Brand{"Gucci"}`

Comment: it will showing result with [] (square brackets), how to remove it? @nu11p01n73R

Comment: @AlanEl-ninoMalmsteen, you see square brackets because it is a slice. What do you want to see instead?

Answer (score 1):

Line 22 should be: `brands = []Brand{Brand{"Gucci"}}`